# compare to strings having same characters or alphabets

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java programming and recently started working on string operations.
Can anyone suggest me a working idea to check whether to string consists of same character sets?

Example:

```
string1="add" so string1 has characters "a,d"
string2="dad" so string2 has characters "a,d"
--> they match

String1="abc"
string2="abcd"
--> they don't match
```

I don't want letter by letter comparison

Comment: Dear Rohan: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to find information about how to ask a good question.  I'm afraid that your question in it's current form would be closed soon.

Comment: do you want to check two strings for equality ??

Comment: @devnull: It's not brilliantly written, but it seems reasonably clear to me. I'm starting on an answer :)

Comment: @saurabh sharma: ya i want to compare two strings with the content letter matches

Comment: @devnull:thanks for your suggestion will keep in mind and this is the first time for me to quote a question definitely suggestions help me out to project good question in future and even answers tooo

Comment: @user3382583 what about the string length? Should it be equal?

Comment: @Sandeep:irrespective of string length say string1="add"  and string2="dadd"

Comment: @Jan Doggen:thanks for editing now I understand how to post a question in rite way thanks for updating me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to check whether the set of characters contained within one string is the same as the set of characters contained within another. That's reasonably easy to achieve with a `Set<Character>`:

```
static boolean characterSetsEqual(String text1, String text2) {
    Set<Character> set1 = toCharacterSet(text1);
    Set<Character> set2 = toCharacterSet(text2);
    return set1.equals(set2);
}

static Set<Character> toCharacterSet(String input) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        set.add(input.charAt(i));
    }
    return set;
}
```

[`Set<>.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is defined in exactly the way that you want it to be:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.

It's important to see that you really are interested in *sets* here - the conversion from a `String` (which is a sequence of characters) into a `Set<Character>` (which has no inherent order, nor a count of how many times each character appears) is the crucial part.

Comment: While your answer would do what the OP wants, I'm afraid that it would be of much help to the OP in terms of _understanding_.  I'm sorry to say that in it's current form the answer looks like a _code dump_ (assuming that you set out to answer in order to _educate somebody_).

Comment: @devnull: Well it certainly wasn't *just* a code dump even to start with, but I've now expanded it further.

Comment: @JonSkeet:jon thanks for ur response my goal is achieved and am comfortable with set conversion thanks for the explanation too but it would be more help full for me if i would have got the explanation part instead of code part so that atleast i can bend my brain into tricky fun java part but thanks this given me futher more   enthusiasm to decoe few more string operations

Comment: @rohan: What explanation do you need that isn't currently within the answer? Or do you mean you'd have preferred an explanation *without* sample code?

Comment: @JonSkeet:thats great you provided the code ya i would rather prefer explanation without sample code so that the idea make to blend with java coding with which only i can improve my self

Answer (score 0):

This is simple library that might help you with bassic operations on strings for the [begening](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)  and also please look at String class documentation there are also many usefull stuff.